# Forwarding emails not working

Tags: domains, webmail

I bought a new domain for myself. I got an email account free with the domain. Inorder to access mails through my gmail account I set up auto-forwarding all mails from my domain's webmail. Now the problem is at times it forwards mails instantly but sometimes it doesn't. Can anything be done about it?

Comment: Do you know the webmail software? When it doesn't forward instantly, does it arrive eventually or is it lost?

Comment: I don't know what is the software used. Is there a way to find out? So far I got all the test mails sent by me from other IDs, some after 30+ mins. Can it so happen that they don't arrive at all? I am asking because I plan not to open the actual inbox frequently.

Comment: Does it say on the screen when you look at the webmail? If you turn off the forwarding, then they won't arrive at all. Is that what you want?

Comment: No nothing appears on screen. I went to settings and gave my gmail address as forward address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many places where delays could occur in the path between your domain and Google's servers. No, there's not a lot you can do about that.

Comment: That's good to know. Can it so happen that the forwarded mail does not arrive at my gmail inbox at all? Also I have experienced while registering at newsgroup like sites the confirmation mails don't come at all in Yahoo(I have a Yahoo account too). How do such things happen. For the same group if I subscribe with a gmail ID I don't face any issues!

Comment: Email is not guaranteed to be reliable, so it is possible for emails to get lost on the way. It is also possible that Google's or Yahoo's spam filters put them in your spam folder.

Comment: Alright. In some situations I didn't have expected mails from newsgroup registrations in Yahoo's spam box too.